# How to create RTK-Query endpoint types when using codesplitting

Tags: typescript, rtk-query

I'm currently building out an an rtk-query package for an application, where I am making use of code-splitting (by using `injectEndpoints`, since there will likely be hundreds of endpoints involved). However, I'd also like to implement a prefetch hook similar to [the automatic prefetch hook in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/prefetching#recipe-prefetch-immediately).

Is there a way to generate proper Typescript types for these endpoints? The above hook defines the endpoint types as `type EndpointNames = keyof typeof api.endpoints`, however all my endpoints are defined like this (as described by the docs):

```
export const emptySplitApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: () => ({}), //
})
```

If this isn't possible, what's the best way to export multiple `usePrefetch` hooks from different `injectEndpoints` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just export the full api object from each file and then be like `api1.usePrefetch()`, `api2.usePrefetch()`.

That way you make also sure that the right file has been loaded, so it is injected. If you were to call that on the parent api, you could never be sure if the endpoint had already been injected.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { EndpointDefinitions } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API_BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (): EndpointDefinitions => ({} as EndpointDefinitions),
});
```

I am late but this worked for me by casting return type of `endpoints` to `EndpointDefinitions` from rtk query.